# How to mysql left join and echo variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join

friends i try to mysql left join query on php side and i need little bit help.
 I can not query as php object, if i  query object, query was empty:  $data=$categories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

How can i query as php object?

```
<?php
$categories = $vt->prepare("SELECT t1.baslik AS lev1, t2.baslik as lev2, t3.baslik as lev3, t4.baslik as lev4
FROM menuler AS t1
LEFT JOIN menuler AS t2 ON t2.katID = t1.id
LEFT JOIN menuler AS t3 ON t3.katID = t2.id
LEFT JOIN menuler AS t4 ON t4.katID = t3.id WHERE t1.katID=?");

foreach ($listeSonuc as $listele) {
    # code...
 }

$categories->execute(array($listele->katID));
$data=$categories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$categoriesResult = array_map(function($item){
    return (object)array_combine(['lev1', 'lev2', 'lev3', 'lev4'], $item);
},$data);

// code begins here
$newData = [];
foreach ($categoriesResult as $row) {
    $tree = get_object_vars($row);
    do {
        $title = array_pop($tree);
    } while($title === null);
    $catTree = implode(' > ', $tree);
    $newData[] = (object)[
        'title' => $title,
        'tree'  => $catTree
    ];
}?>
<div class="table">
        <div>
            <div class="th">Başlık</div>
            <div class="th kucukteldegizle">Bölüm</div>
            <div class="th kucukteldegizle">Özellik</div>
            <div class="th kucukteldegizle">Yayınla?</div>
            <div class="th text-right">İşlem</div>              
        </div>

<?php foreach ($newData as $row) {?>
        <div class="cizgili">
            <div class='bosluk'><?php echo $row->title?></div>
            <div class="kucukteldegizle"><?php echo $row->tree?></div>
            <div class="kucukteldegizle">???</div>
            <div class="kucukteldegizle">???</div>
            <div>???</div>
        </div>
<?php }?>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the line breaks in the SQL query are creating the issue. Put the SQL query in a single line, it will work.

Comment: All your images show tables which you can just post as formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly i fixed it with different technique:

In SQL section i created a Function:

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE res TEXT;
        CALL catpath(cat_id, res);
        RETURN res;
    END
```

Then i created a Procedure:

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE catname VARCHAR(300);
        DECLARE temppath TEXT;
        DECLARE tempparent INT;
        SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
        SELECT baslik, katID FROM categories WHERE id=cat_id INTO catname,        tempparent;
        IF tempparent IS NULL
        THEN
            SET path = catname;
        ELSE
            CALL catpath(tempparent, temppath);
            SET path = CONCAT(temppath, '/', catname);
        END IF;
    END
```

Then i call my php codes:

```
   <?php
     $sql = $vt->prepare ("SELECT id, baslik, catpath(id) AS path FROM menuler WHERE id = '$kayitListesi->id' ");
     $sql ->execute(array());
     $sqlsonuc=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($sqlsonuc);
         foreach($sqlsonuc as $kategoriagaci){
             echo $kategoriagaci->path;
         }
     ?>
```

Then i get my category tree:

```
Electronics/Computers/Desktop Computers/Asus Desktop I7
```

Hope, helps to anybody

Answer (score 1):

`FETCH_OBJ` flag returns each row as a php object. so your code should be like this.

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>lev1</th><th>lev2</th><th>lev3</th><th>lev4</th></tr>';
foreach ($categoriesResult as $titles) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$titles->lev1}</td><td>{$titles->lev2}</td><td>{$titles->lev3}</td><td>{$titles->lev4}</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

this should display your result.

Comment: i have edited a typo in my answer. If this not resolve your problem can you tell me are getting any errors with this or what was the output.

Comment: Sorry, still not correct results, please see my top question for "How can i get this results in php side:" section, i posted correct result in there.

Comment: do you need results in html table or as simple text with aligned content

Comment: I need results in html div  formatted as html like this: <style>

       .table { width: 100%; display: table; }
       .table div { display: table-row; }
       .table div div { display: table-cell; text-align: left; }
       .table div div.th { font-weight: bold; text-align: left; }

       div.cizgili:nth-child(2n){
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
    .bosluk{
        padding: 5px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 576px) {
        .kucukteldegizle{
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;

        }
    }
</style>

Comment: i changed my answer please try it now.

Comment: Yes thanks display results but, something is wrong myside, i updated something, trying.. I can not update image to stackoverflow, images is not displayed.

Comment: please check my top question i edited it, i added to my external website image links, because i can not add images to here..

Answer (score 1):

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($categoriesResult as $row) {
    $tree = get_object_vars($row);
    do {
        $title = array_pop($tree);
    } while($title === null);
    $catTree = implode(' > ', $tree);
    $newData[] = (object)[
        'title' => $title,
        'tree'  => $catTree
    ];
}
```

`$newData` will now look like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'title' => 'Sony 72 Ekran Led Television',
     'tree' => 'All Televisions > Led Televisions > Sony Led Televisions',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'title' => 'Samsung 142" Lcd Television',
     'tree' => 'All Televisions > Led Televisions > Samsung Lcd Televisions',
  )),
  2 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'title' => 'Uhd Televisions',
     'tree' => 'All Televisions',
  )),
)
```

Demo: https://rextester.com/IOCYY93067

which is an array of `stdClass` objects with attributes `title` (first column) and `tree` (second column).

Now you just need to render it as HTML table.

Here is an example how you can render the output:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>CATEGORIE</th>
    <th>PROPERTIES</th>
    <th>POSTED?</th>
    <th><!-- edit/delete --></th>
</tr>';
foreach ($newData as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$row->title}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row->tree}</td>";
    echo "<td>???</td>";
    echo "<td>???</td>";
    echo "<td>???</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Demo: https://rextester.com/IRF19069

Comment: my problem is css related?  print_r($newData);  http://www.doganozcine.com/dosyalar/ScreenShot.png

Comment: thanks for update, i will try it, but can i get results in a div, that div formatted as table

Comment: How can get result as php object? $data=$categories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: You already have it in the question: `$categoriesResult=$categories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: If i query as object  results is empty otherwise it is ok:   $categories->execute(array($listele->katID));
$data=$categories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$categoriesResult = array_map(function($item){
    return (object)array_combine(['lev1', 'lev2', 'lev3', 'lev4'], $item);
},$data);


$newData = [];
foreach ($categoriesResult as $row) {
    $tree = get_object_vars($row);
    do {
        $title = array_pop($tree);
    } while($title === null);
    $catTree = implode(' > ', $tree);
    $newData[] = (object)[
        'title' => $title,
        'tree'  => $catTree
    ];
}?>

Comment: You already have the code in the question `if($count > 0){
  foreach ($categoriesResult as $titles) {                                
        // put my code here
    }
}`

Comment: i need this structure, please see image =>  http://www.doganozcine.com/dosyalar/NORMAL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoriesResult=$categories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($categoriesResult as $title => $value) {
    echo "$title = $value";
}
```

Comment: Hi Nasir, coud you elaborate a little bit more about this code, why do you think this answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($categoriesResult as $title) {                                
    echo $title->lev1;
    echo $title->lev2;
}
```

This is how you should be able to access your values. You can of course put HTML into your echo statements to format the result.

Comment: please check my top question i edited it, i added to my external website image links, because i can not add images to here..

Comment: are you able to extract the data correctly? No matter how it looks, but can you echo the data you need? After that we can talk about formatting, as these are two different problems.

Comment: no, i can not get correct results, if you see my three images you can see that. If i print_r() results are not correct.